# how Inject headers to OmniAuth mock tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, omniauth-google-oauth2

I'm using omniauth-google-oauth2 gem to log in via google account. recently I saw this post https://developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/guidance-for-our-effort-to-block-less-secure-browser-and-apps.html. even though it will not affect to the regular users I'm  worried about unit tests. which i guess use headless browsers. so I would like to test that by injecting headers as described in this post(`Google-Accounts-Check-OAuth-Login:true`).  couldn't find any api methods for that on omiauth documentations.

```rb
 OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:google] = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new(
      provider: "google",
      uid: "123545",
      info: {
        email: EMAIL,
        first_name: FIRST_NAME,
        last_name: LAST_NAME,
      }
    )

    visit new_user_registration_path
    click_link "Sign in with Google"
```